# ActiveSheet.Range.Select returns error 462 "The remote server machine does not exist"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

This should be simple but I can't see the problem after trying many different code variations.  The first time I run the code it selects the cell "B4" to the end of column.  The next time I run it I get the error 426, "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable".  Then I run it again and it runs correctly.  Then the next time I get the error. Etc. Crazy!

```
Dim g_OBJ_EXCEL_APP As Excel.Application
Dim g_OBJ_EXcel_WB As Excel.Workbook
Dim str_Cell_Ref As String, str_excel_filename As String, strSheetName as String
Dim g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Call sForceAllExcelProcessClose 'Just to make sure its not causing a problem I kill all Excel before I start
    Set g_OBJ_EXCEL_APP = New Excel.Application
    str_excel_filename = "\\ahw.cc2.zone\ahw$\Users\rotto_ahw-global.com\Documents\Sample1.xlsx"
    Set g_OBJ_EXcel_WB = g_OBJ_EXCEL_APP.Workbooks.Open(str_excel_filename)
    strSheetName = "Sheet1"
    Set g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS = g_OBJ_EXcel_WB.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    g_OBJ_EXCEL_APP.Application.Visible = True
    str_Cell_Ref = "B4"
    g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS.Range(str_Cell_Ref, Range(str_Cell_Ref).End(xlDown)).Select 'This is where the error occurs

    Set g_OBJ_EXcel_WB = Nothing
    Set g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS = Nothing
    Set g_OBJ_EXCEL_APP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `Range` in your command line

```
g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS.Range(str_Cell_Ref, Range(str_Cell_Ref).End(xlDown)).Select
```

is not fully qualified. So it defaults to `ActiveSheet.Range`. But `ActiveSheet` might not be available because the code runs inside `Microsoft Access` and not `Excel`. Hence the error.

Do

```
g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS.Range(str_Cell_Ref, g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS.Range(str_Cell_Ref).End(xlDown)).Select
```

That fully qualifies the `Range` to be a range in sheet `g_OBJ_EXCEL_WS`.